# Rails count number of records in polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a polymorphic association in my application and I want to be able to count the number of users in a group, and list the users in each group. How can I achieve this?

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_groups
  has_many :users, through: :user_groups
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_groups
  has_many :groups, through: :user_groups
end

class UserGroup < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
end
```

I at the moment I can call `User.first.groups` however I am not able to call `User.groups.all` and `User.all.groups` but none of these work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, that's not a polymorphic association. Just FYI.

It's hard to know what you're asking, because to count the users in a group, you do:

```
group.users.count
```

When you say, 'list them', do you mean in a view? That would be something like:

```
<%- group.users.each do |user| %>
  # do something with user
<% end %>
```

Just to expand on the comment, if the class `Image` had a polymorphic `belongs_to` association, that might look something like:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: images
#
#  id               :integer          not null, primary key
#  imageable_id     :integer
#  imageable_type   :string
#  created_at       :datetime         not null
#  updated_at       :datetime         not null
#
class Image < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
end
```

As you can see, the `Image` class has the attributes of `imageable_id` and `imageable_type`. Then, if you wanted to have `Document` have many `images`, you would same something like:

```
class Document < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :images, as: :imageable
end
```

Then you could do:

```
image.imageable
```

To get the object that the `image` belongs to. To get all the `images` for a `document`, then simply:

```
document.images
```

Comment: What would this be called if not a polymorphic association? Your solution did work for me. I suppose I was overthinking.

Comment: This is a many-to-many relationship. Polymorphic is - a model can effectively belong to multiple other models. Example - Image can belong to User or Document. So, one might have a layer called as `imageable` in Image representing polymorphism for `User` and `Document`.

Comment: To be a little more precise, with a polymorphic association as discussed, an `image` object can belong to only one other object. But, that object can be of any `class`. As you say, for example, an instance of `User` or `Document`. With `belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true`, `imageable` and `imageable=` are methods that are available on the `image` object which allow for getting/setting - which is perhaps what you meant by 'a layer'.